# Is there a way to play .mxf video on Android?

Tags: android, video, video-encoding, codec, transcoding

According to developer.android.com, the Android supports the playing of video using the H.263, H.264 AVC, MPEG4 SP and VP8 codecs. However, I want to play a video encoded in the .mxf format (Material eXchange Format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXF) in my app. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MXF generally contains MPEG-2 / AVC video with profile/levels not supported by the decoders in the android devices. Specifically IMX is 422 profile at main level and HD MPEG-2 MXF is generally 422 profile at high level.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of the thumb says that you must use the most common and less resource intensive codec. Bad video playback is a deal breaker. Maybe you know the huge difference that format makes but the user won't.